# Rundeck log output isn't refreshed online for python scripts

Tags: python, rundeck

I create simple job in Rundeck, with only one bash script step:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}
do
   echo "$i"
   sleep 5
done
```

Log output for it's build is:

```
22:26:12    1
22:26:17    2
22:26:22    3
22:26:27    4
22:26:32    5
22:26:37    6
22:26:42    7
22:26:47    8
22:26:52    9
22:26:57    10
```

As you can see, `echo` command is printed after exactly 5 seconds after previous `echo`.

Now Python version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time

for i in range(10):
   print i
   time.sleep(5)
```

Log output:

```
22:29:17    0
22:29:17    1
22:29:17    2
22:29:17    3
22:29:17    4
22:29:17    5
22:29:17    6
22:29:17    7
22:29:17    8
22:29:17    9
```

This time whole log was printed at once after finishing job.

Is there any chance to get the same logging way for Python's scripts as for bash ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, python buffers output until completion. If you set the `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable, it will not buffer but print the output as the script runs.

https://www.systutorials.com/how-to-flush-stdout-buffer-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

It works in this way:

```py
import os
import time

for i in range(10):
   os.system('echo ' + str(i))
   time.sleep(5)
```

PD: good catch.